# How do I display Google Map controls on mouseover (hover)?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

How would I go about displaying the standard Google Map controls when the user hovers their mouse over the map? I would like the controls to otherwise be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for that, you can do it with the Maps API.

```
 function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
      disableDefaultUI:true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                  myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function() {
    map.setOptions({
      disableDefaultUI:false
});
  });
  }
```

Comment: I show the controls at `mouseover` and disable them at `mouseout`. But when I move the mouse over the controls, the `mouseout` event is triggered even if I'm still inside the map container. What's a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal javascript addEventListener to make it work. The google.maps.event.addListener way will fire mouseout when you hover a control on the map.

```
document.getElementById("map_canvas").addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  map.setOptions({
    disableDefaultUI:true
  });
});
document.getElementById("map_canvas").addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  map.setOptions({
    disableDefaultUI:false
  });
});
```